# TensorFlow: How do I generate a dataset from two arrays?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I've been trying to generate a custom dataset from two arrays. One with the shape `(128,128,6)` (satellite data with 6 channels), and the other with the shape `(128,128,1)` (binary mask). I have been using the function `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_raster, train_mask))
```

What I get is this:

```
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 6), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

However, when I try to run this through my model I get this error:

```
ValueError ValueError: `Shapes (None, 128, 128, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible
```

`(None, 2)` since my output is one of 2 classes.

In a tutorial I've seen the dataset as `<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 128, 128, 3), (None, 128, 128, 1)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>`. Is there a difference, and if so, how do I fix it? It seems like only one of the two tensors is being run through the model, but I don't quite understand why.

Model definition:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(128, 128, 6)), tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2), 
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu), 
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2), 
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid) 
])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The binary mask is your label? Please attach your model architecture or model definition code to your question. Your model architecture is not compatible with the dataset you are feeding to it.

Comment: I can guess that your last layer outputs 2 neurons (for binary mask). But since you have specified an array with the shape `(128,128,1)` in your dataset, it leads to an error. If you just passed the `train_dataset` to your model, it considers the first part of tuple (first array) as input and the second array (128,128,1) as your labels.

Comment: Thank you! This is my model architecture:
`model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3),
padding='same',
activation=tf.nn.relu,
input_shape=(128, 128, 6)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])`

Comment: Yes, the mask represents my labels. Either 0 or 1 for every pixel within the array. How do I pass the `train_dataset` with both arrays to my model? I thought I did that by defining the dataset. How do I not specify the shape of my mask when that's just what the array looks like?

Comment: If you print your model summary, you will see your model output is just two numbers (None,2). But you need output as (128,128,1). So, your dataset is ok. You need to modify your model architecture. For example an architecture like `U-Net`.

Comment: Thank you! I did change the architecture and now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **@Kaveh** comments in the answer section for **the benefit of the community** as this fixed the user's issue. (Thank you @Kaveh)

> I can guess that your last layer outputs 2 neurons (for binary mask).
> But since you have specified an array with the shape (128,128,1) in
> your dataset, it leads to an error. If you just passed the
> train_dataset to your model, it considers the first part of tuple
> (first array) as input and the second array (128,128,1) as your labels
>
> If you print your model summary, you will see your model output is
> just two numbers (None,2). But you need output as (128,128,1). So,
> your dataset is ok. You need to modify your model architecture. For
> example an architecture like U-Net.